# maps with react components

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, ecmascript-6, jsx

I have the next code:

```
 const compsMap = new Map([
    ['id',          <TableHeaderColumn dataField={'id'} width='50' isKey autoValue={true} dataAlign='left' dataSort >{'id'}</TableHeaderColumn>],
    ['firstName',   <TableHeaderColumn dataField={'firstName'} dataSort headerAlign='left' editable={JSON.parse('{"type": "textarea" }')}>{'First Name'}</TableHeaderColumn>],
    ['lastName',    <TableHeaderColumn dataField={'lastName'} dataSort headerAlign='left'  editable={JSON.parse('{"type": "textarea" }')}>{'Last Name'}</TableHeaderColumn>],
    ['mobile',      <TableHeaderColumn dataField={'mobile'} dataSort headerAlign='left'    editable={JSON.parse('{"type": "textarea" }')}>{'Mobile'}</TableHeaderColumn>],
    ['username',    <TableHeaderColumn dataField={'username'} dataSort headerAlign='left'  editable={JSON.parse('{"type": "textarea" }')}>{'Username'}</TableHeaderColumn>],
    ['password',    <TableHeaderColumn dataField={'password'} dataSort headerAlign='left'  editable={JSON.parse('{"type": "textarea" }')}>{'Password'}</TableHeaderColumn>],
]); 

console.log('compsMap[id] = ' + compsMap['id']);
```

why I get compsMap['id'] as  Undefined?

Please, assume that each

```
<TableHeaderColumn... > ... </TableHeaderColumn>
```

is well defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `compsMap.get(key)` to get the value.

Check this example:

```js
const compsMap = new Map([
    ['id', "<TableHeaderColumn dataField={'id'} width='50' isKey autoValue={true} dataAlign='left' dataSort >{'id'}</TableHeaderColumn>"],
    ['firstName', "<TableHeaderColumn dataField={'firstName'} dataSort headerAlign='left' editable={JSON.parse('{type: 'textarea' }')}>{'First Name'}</TableHeaderColumn>"],
    ['lastName', "<TableHeaderColumn dataField={'lastName'} dataSort headerAlign='left'  editable={JSON.parse('{'type': 'textarea' }')}>{'Last Name'}</TableHeaderColumn>"],
    ['mobile',  "<TableHeaderColumn dataField={'mobile'} dataSort headerAlign='left'    editable={JSON.parse('{'type': 'textarea' }')}>{'Mobile'}</TableHeaderColumn>"],
    ['username', "<TableHeaderColumn dataField={'username'} dataSort headerAlign='left'  editable={JSON.parse('{'type': 'textarea' }')}>{'Username'}</TableHeaderColumn>"]
]); 

console.log('compsMap[id] = ', compsMap.get('id'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in the way you are trying to get at your data. Consider the following example

```
let map = new Map([
  ['id', 'foobar']
]);

console.log(map['id']) //undefined
```

vs

```
let map = new Map([
  ['id', 'foobar']
]);

console.log(map.get('id')) // 'foobar'
```

Hope this helps.